# How to do n-D distance and nearest neighbor calculations on numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

**This question is intended to be a canonical duplicate target**

Given two arrays `X` and `Y` of shapes `(i, n)` and `(j, n)`, representing lists of `n`-dimensional coordinates,

```
def test_data(n, i, j, r = 100):
    X = np.random.rand(i, n) * r - r / 2
    Y = np.random.rand(j, n) * r - r / 2
    return X, Y

X, Y = test_data(3, 1000, 1000)
```

what are the fastest ways to find:

1. The distance `D` with shape `(i,j)` between every point in `X` and every point in `Y`
2. The indices `k_i` and distance `k_d` of the `k` nearest neighbors against all points in `X` for every point in `Y`
3. The indices `r_i`, `r_j` and distance `r_d` of every point in `X` within distance `r` of every point `j` in `Y`

Given the following sets of restrictions:

- Only using `numpy`
- Using any `python` package

Including the special case:

- `Y` is `X`

In all cases [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) primarily means [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Distance_in_Euclidean_space), but feel free to highlight methods that allow other distance calculations.

Comment: From my experience with numpy, using overloaded operators with internal broadcasting, overwriting the variables, and writing most of the calculations in one-line (so GIL will apply) will be the fastest way. For instance, to measure the distance from *vector* `x` to *matrix* `Y` you should use `dists = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(Y-x),axis=1))`. If you do not need the actual distance, but only the sum of squares, drop the `np.sqrt` operation. Also, since in this method you iterate at least one axis, use the minimum `min(X.shape[0],Y.shape[0])` for iterations. Packages: use sklearn implementation.

Comment: B.T.W you also have many implemented methods such as `np.argsort`, etc., which will become handful for your implementation. If you iterate samples, you maybe want to invest a little on parallel computing the distances between samples and matrices, using the `multiprocessing` native package.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#1. All Distances

- **only using `numpy`**

The naive method is:

```
D = np.sqrt(np.sum((X[:, None, :] - Y[None, :, :])**2, axis = -1))
```

However this takes up a lot of memory creating an `(i, j, n)`-shaped intermediate matrix, and is very slow

However, thanks to a trick from @Divakar ([`eucl_dist`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist) package, [wiki](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article#prospective-method)), we can use a bit of algebra and [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to decompose as such:  `(X - Y)**2 = X**2 - 2*X*Y + Y**2`

```
D = np.sqrt(                                #  (X - Y) ** 2   
np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', X, X)[:, None] +    # = X ** 2        \
np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', Y, Y)          -    # + Y ** 2        \
2 * X.dot(Y.T))                             # - 2 * X * Y
```

- **`Y` is `X`**

Similar to above:

```
XX = np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', X, X)
D = np.sqrt(XX[:, None] + XX - 2 * X.dot(X.T))
```

Beware that floating-point imprecision can make the diagonal terms deviate very slightly from zero with this method.  If you need to make sure they are zero, you'll need to explicitly set it:

```
np.einsum('ii->i', D)[:] = 0
```

- **Any Package**

[`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) is the most intuitive builtin function for this, and far faster than bare `numpy`

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
D = cdist(X, Y)
```

`cdist` can also deal with many, many distance measures as well as user-defined distance measures (although these are not optimized).  Check the documentation linked above for details.

- **`Y` is `X`**

For self-referring distances, [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) works similar to `cdist`, but returns a 1-D condensed distance array, saving space on the symmetric distance matrix by only having each term once.  You can convert this to a square matrix using [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform)

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
D_cond = pdist(X)
D = squareform(D_cond)
```

#2. K Nearest Neighbors (KNN)

- **Only using `numpy`**

We could use `np.argpartition` to get the `k-nearest` indices and use those to get the corresponding distance values. So, with `D` as the array holding the distance values obtained above, we would have -

```
if k == 1:
    k_i = D.argmin(0)
else:
    k_i = D.argpartition(k, axis = 0)[:k]
k_d = np.take_along_axis(D, k_i, axis = 0)
```

However we can speed this up a bit by not taking the square roots until we have reduced our dataset.  `np.sqrt` is the slowest part of calculating the Euclidean norm, so we don't want to do that until the end.

```
D_sq = np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', X, X)[:, None] +\
       np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', Y, Y) - 2 * X.dot(Y.T)
if k == 1:
    k_i = D_sq.argmin(0)
else:
    k_i = D_sq.argpartition(k, axis = 0)[:k]
k_d = np.sqrt(np.take_along_axis(D_sq, k_i, axis = 0))
```

Now, `np.argpartition` performs indirect partition and doesn't necessarily give us the elements in sorted order and only makes sure that the first `k` elements are the smallest ones. So, for a sorted output, we need to use `argsort` on the output from previous step -

```
sorted_idx = k_d.argsort(axis = 0)
k_i_sorted = np.take_along_axis(k_i, sorted_idx, axis = 0)
k_d_sorted = np.take_along_axis(k_d, sorted_idx, axis = 0)
```

If you only need, `k_i`, you never need the square root at all:

```
D_sq = np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', X, X)[:, None] +\
       np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', Y, Y) - 2 * X.dot(Y.T)
if k == 1:
    k_i = D_sq.argmin(0)
else:
    k_i = D_sq.argpartition(k, axis = 0)[:k]
k_d_sq = np.take_along_axis(D_sq, k_i, axis = 0)
sorted_idx = k_d_sq.argsort(axis = 0)
k_i_sorted = np.take_along_axis(k_i, sorted_idx, axis = 0)
```

- **`X` is `Y`**

In the above code, replace:

```
D_sq = np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', X, X)[:, None] +\
       np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', Y, Y) - 2 * X.dot(Y.T)
```

with:

```
XX = np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', X, X)
D_sq = XX[:, None] + XX - 2 * X.dot(X.T))
```

- **Any Package**

[KD-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is a much faster method to find neighbors and constrained distances.  Be aware the while KDTree is usually much faster than brute force solutions above for 3d (as long as oyu have more than 8 points), if you have `n`-dimensions, KDTree only scales well if you have  more than `2**n` points.  For discussion and more advanced methods for high dimensions, see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751114/nearest-neighbors-in-high-dimensional-data?rq=1)

The most recommended method for implementing KDTree is to use `scipy`'s [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) or [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
X_tree = KDTree(X)
k_d, k_i = X_tree.query(Y, k = k)
```

Unfortunately `scipy`'s KDTree implementation is slow and has a tendency to segfault for larger data sets.  As pointed out by @HansMusgrave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52361176/4427777), [`pykdtree`](https://github.com/storpipfugl/pykdtree) increases the performance a lot, but is not as common an include as `scipy` and can only deal with Euclidean distance currently (while the `KDTree` in `scipy` can handle Minkowsi p-norms of any order)

- **`X` is `Y`**

Use instead:

```
k_d, k_i = X_tree.query(X, k = k)
```

- **Arbitrary metrics**

A BallTree has similar algorithmic properties to a KDTree. I'm not aware of a parallel/vectorized/fast BallTree in Python, but using scipy we can still have reasonable KNN queries for user-defined metrics. If available, builtin metrics will be much faster.

```
def d(a, b):
    return max(np.abs(a-b))

tree = sklearn.neighbors.BallTree(X, metric=d)
k_d, k_i = tree.query(Y)
```

This answer **will be wrong** if `d()` is not a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). The only reason a BallTree is faster than brute force is because the properties of a metric allow it to rule out some solutions. For truly arbitrary functions, brute force is actually necessary.

#3. Radius search

- **Only using `numpy`**

The simplest method is just to use boolean indexing:

```
mask = D_sq < r**2
r_i, r_j = np.where(mask)
r_d = np.sqrt(D_sq[mask])
```

- **Any Package**

Similar to above, you can use `scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point`

```
r_ij = X_tree.query_ball_point(Y, r = r)
```

or `scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree`

```
Y_tree = KDTree(Y)
r_ij = X_tree.query_ball_tree(Y_tree, r = r)
```

Unfortunately `r_ij` ends up being a list of index arrays that are a bit difficult to untangle for later use.

Much easier is to use `cKDTree`'s `sparse_distance_matrix`, which can output a `coo_matrix`

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
X_cTree = cKDTree(X)
Y_cTree = cKDTree(Y)
D_coo = X_cTree.sparse_distance_matrix(Y_cTree, r = r, output_type = `coo_matrix`)
r_i = D_coo.row
r_j = D_coo.column
r_d = D_coo.data
```

This is an extraordinarily flexible format for the distance matrix, as it stays an actual matrix (if converted to `csr`) can also be used for many vectorized operations.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that since the square root is monotonic we can use the einsum directly and not bother with `np.sqrt`?

Comment: I have put that under #2, once we start reducing the number of distances we want to return.  For part #1 we need all distances, so we need he square root of everything.

Comment: Is using ```np.einsum``` to compute ```D_sq``` faster than using ```pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')```?

Comment: @Joe, `D_sq` is used in cases of `numpy`-only calculation (many 3rd party scripting APIs implement `numpy` but not other packages).  `pdist` is a `scipy` function