# np.where() to eliminate data, where coordinates are too close to each other

Tags: python, numpy, astronomy

I'm doing aperture photometry on a cluster of stars, and to get easier detection of background signal, I want to only look at stars further apart than n pixels (n=16 in my case).
I have 2 arrays, xs and ys, with the x- and y-values of all the stars' coordinates:
Using np.where I'm supposed to find the indexes of all stars, where the distance to all other stars is >= n

So far, my method has been a for-loop

```py
import numpy as np

# Lists of coordinates w. values between 0 and 2000 for 5000 stars

xs = np.random.rand(5000)*2000
ys = np.random.rand(5000)*2000

# for-loop, wherein the np.where statement in  question is situated
n = 16
for i in range(len(xs)):
    index = np.where( np.sqrt( pow(xs[i] - xs,2) + pow(ys[i] - ys,2)) >= n)
```

Due to the stars being clustered pretty closely together, I expected a severe reduction in data, though even when I tried n=1000 I still had around 4000 datapoints left

Comment: Are you restricted to `numpy` only?  Can you use `scipy`?

Comment: I do not know how did you get those 4000 datapoints left. First, the way you are using the random is incorrect, that creates a 2D array where the second dimension has 5000 elements.. if you want 5000 elements between 0 and 2000 you can do **np.random.rand(5000)*2000** . Also the np.where is not doing what you want. If you try to print index you will see it returns an array each time not a index.

Comment: Changed the random datapoints to actually work. I'm not restricted to numpy per se, but I prefer keeping stuff as simple as possible

Answer (score 2):

Using just `numpy` (and part of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366421/how-to-do-n-d-distance-and-nearest-neighbor-calculations-on-numpy-arrays/52366706#52366706))

```
X = np.random.rand(5000,2) * 2000
XX = np.einsum('ij, ij ->i', X, X)
D_squared = XX[:, None] + XX - 2 * X.dot(X.T)
out = np.where(D_squared.min(axis = 0) > n**2)
```

Using `scipy.spatial.pdist`

```
from scipy.spatial import pdist, squareform
D_squared = squareform(pdist(x, metric = 'sqeuclidean'))
out = np.where(D_squared.min(axis = 0) > n**2)
```

Using a KDTree for maximum fast:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

X_tree = KDTree(X)
in_radius = np.array(list(X_tree.query_pairs(n))).flatten()
out = np.where(~np.in1d(np.arange(X.shape[0]), in_radius))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.random.seed(seed=1)
xs = np.random.rand(5000,1)*2000
ys = np.random.rand(5000,1)*2000

n = 16

mask = (xs>=0)

for i in range(len(xs)):
    if mask[i]:
        index = np.where( np.sqrt( pow(xs[i] - x,2) + pow(ys[i] - y,2)) <= n)
        mask[index] = False
        mask[i] = True

x = xs[mask]
y = ys[mask]

print(len(x))
```

> 4220

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.subtract.outer` for creating the pairwise comparisons. Then you check for each row whether the distance is below 16 for exactly one item (which is the comparison with the particular start itself):

```
distances = np.sqrt(
    np.subtract.outer(xs, xs)**2
    + np.subtract.outer(ys, ys)**2
)
indices = np.nonzero(np.sum(distances < 16, axis=1) == 1)
```