# How to calculate the distance between two points on lines in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, numpy, math

I have two lines. namely `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`. I need to calculate the distance between the points. see my code snippets below

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1= np.array([525468.80914272, 525468.70536016])
y1= np.array([175517.80433391, 175517.75493122])

x2= np.array([525468.81174, 525468.71252])
y2= np.array([175517.796305, 175517.74884 ])
```

Here is the code for the plot:

```
fig= go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1, name="point1"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2, name="point2"))
```

See the figure here

[image: 1]

The black line is the distance I want to calculate

my expectations are: `(0.008438554274975979, 0.0085878435595034274819)`

Comment: don't you have any correct answers so we could check if the provided solution is correct or not?

Comment: I think your lines are from (x1[0],y1[0]) to (x1[1],y1[1]), and from (x2[0],y2[0]) to (x2[1],y2[1]). right?

Comment: yes, feels right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do n-D distance and nearest neighbor calculations on numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366421/how-to-do-n-d-distance-and-nearest-neighbor-calculations-on-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with `math` library

```
import math

distancePointA  = math.sqrt(((x1[0] - x2[0]) ** 2) + ((y1[0] - y2[0]) ** 2))
distancePointB  = math.sqrt(((x1[1] - x2[1]) ** 2) + ((y1[1] - y2[1]) ** 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

The distance here is just the l2 or euclidian norm. You can use numpy for this.

```
import numpy as np
distance_1 = np.linalg.norm(np.array([x1[0]-x2[0],y1[0]-y2[0]]))
distance_2 = np.linalg.norm(np.array([x1[1]-x2[1],y1[1]-y2[1]]))

print(distance_1,distance_2)
```

output:

```
0.008438557910490769 0.009400333483144686
```

The default norm that np.linalg.norm uses is the euclidian norm. (the distance the black lines represent)

Comment: whoops, my bad. I forgot the brackets. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can calculate the distance using the Pythagoras theorem here I have defined two ways

[image]

- You can get a by `a=x1-x2` and `b=y1-y2` the distance is `c=?`
  passing the value in a formula like

```
 import math
 a=x1-x2
 b=y1-y2

 c=abs(math.sqrt((a** 2) + (b ** 2)))
```

Here in your case

```
import math
a1 = x1[0] - x2[0]
a2 = x1[1] - x2[1]
b1 = y1[0] - y2[0]
b2 = y1[1] - y2[1]

distance_a  = abs(math.sqrt((a1** 2) + (b1** 2)))
distance_b  = abs(math.sqrt((a2** 2) + (b2 ** 2)))
```

- you can use direct `hypot` method which give the same answer like see the equation of `hypot` method [hypot](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-function-hypot/)

```
import math
a1 = x1[0] - x2[0]
a2 = x1[1] - x2[1]
b1 = y1[0] - y2[0]
b2 = y1[1] - y2[1]

distance_a  = math.hypot(a1,b1)
distance_b  = math.hypot(a2,b2)
```

These all are ways you can use any of them but eventually, you get the distances

Comment: I get the error - TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @pandas-py I have changed please check let me know in which case you get this error

Comment: okay it was because math does not work with vectors so I used numpy instead. looks good but I did not get the expectation, which is 0.008438557910490769  for distance_a

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Distance formula** based on Pythagorean Theorem: `AB=√((xA-xB)²+(yA-yB)²)`
where `(xA, yA)`, `(xB, yB)` are the coordinates of the two points A, B.

Apply to your problem:

```py
import math

distance_1  = math.sqrt(((x1[0] - x2[0]) ** 2) + ((y1[0] - y2[0]) ** 2))
distance_2  = math.sqrt(((x1[1] - x2[1]) ** 2) + ((y1[1] - y2[1]) ** 2))

print(distance_1, distance_2)
```

Output:

```py
0.008438557910490769 0.009400333483144686
```