# Python: Calculating the distance between points in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

I would like to calculate the distance between data points in an array.

Example

```
A1 = array([[ 54.        ,  15.        ,   1.        ],
       [ 55.        ,  13.66311896,   1.        ],
       [ 56.        ,  10.16311896,   1.95491503],
       [ 57.        ,   5.83688104,   4.45491503],     # shape 6rows x 3 col
       [ 58.        ,   2.33688104,   7.54508497],
       [ 59.        ,   1.        ,  10.04508497],
       [ 60.        ,   1.        ,  11.        ],
```

Now, I want to calculate the distance between points in column 1 & column 2. and all the distance should be calculated from Row 0 ie.,(x1,y1 = 15,1) but x2,y2 is variable changing from elements row 1 to row6. And I want save this distance as a 'list'. Please help me in solving this in python

Comment: Please post your [example] here. If you tell us what you have tried so far and which errors or problems you are getting, it would be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: dist_matrix = ((A1.reshape(N_points_in_A1, 1, dim_of_point) - A2.reshape(1, N_points_in_A2, dim_of_points))**2).sum(2)**0.5. dist_matrix[i, j] will contain the distance of point i in A1 form point j in A2

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ yann . Could you please explain what is **dim_of_points** & **sum(2)** in `((A1.reshape(N_points_in_A1, 1, dim_of_point) - A2.reshape(1, N_points_in_A2, dim_of_points))**2).sum(2)**0.5. dist_matrix[i, j]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do n-D distance and nearest neighbor calculations on numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366421/how-to-do-n-d-distance-and-nearest-neighbor-calculations-on-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythagoras theorem states `sqrt(a^2+b^2)=c` where `c` is the distance between the tips of the orthogonal lines reaching point `a` and `b`.

```py
import math
from math import sqrt
dist_list=[]
for i in A1[1:]:
    dist=sqrt(pow(A1[0][1]-i[1],2)+pow(A1[0][2]-i[2],2))
    dist_list.append(dist)
```

If you dont want to import `math`:

```py
for i in A1[1:]:
    dist=pow(pow(A1[0][1]-i[1],2)+pow(A1[0][2]-i[2],2),0.5)
    dist_list2.append(dist)
```