# Fast way to extract neighborhoods around selected points in 2D Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NxN array, e.g.

```
test_arr = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
```

I have two points, e.g. `r_vals = (0, 1)`, `c_vals = (2, 0)`.

The *goal* is to extract a neighborhood (nearest-neighbor, i.e. 4 values) for both points **in the fastest way possible**.

That is, I know I could do sth. like

```
nearest_neighs = [[max(c, 0), r], [min(c, N-1), r], [c, max(0, r)], [c, min(r, N-1)]] # left, right, up, down
```

for each point. I could then do unzip these lists to get row and column coordinates for NP fancy indexing, e.g.

`vals = test_arr[indices_r, indices_c]`

I wonder if something that is faster is doable. I have experimented with `np.newaxis`

```
ii = np.arange(-1, 1+1) # Moore neighborhood with distance 1
indices_r, indices_c = np.meshgrid(ii, ii, indexing="ij")

indices_r = indices_r.ravel()[:, np.newaxis] # (9) -> (9, 1)
indices_c = indices_c.ravel()[:, np.newaxis]

points_r = points_r[np.newaxis, :] # (2) -> (1, 2
points_c = points_c[np.newaxis, :]

indices_r = np.add(indices_r, points_r)
indices_c = np.add(indices_c, points_c)
```

However, there I have the problem that A) some indices *exceed* the array (IndexError) and that B) the neighboring indices may overlap.

Does someone have a neat solution for this?

**Edit**

A specific example.

```
test_arr = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=int)
test_arr[[0, 1, 4], [0, 0, 8]] = 1 # set some entries to one

indices_r, indices_c = np.nonzero(test_arr)
```

I want to find the *neighboring* cells of points denoted by `(indices_r[0], indices_c[0])` *without* using a for loop. In addition, I want to check for various other flags.

```
# Test mask
test_mask = np.zeros((10, 10))
test_mask[[2, 4], [0, 8]] = 1
test_mask = test_mask.astype(bool)
```

More precisely, I know I could to something like

```
valid_neighs =[]
for r, c in zip(indices_r, indices_c):
    range_r, range_c = np.arange(r-1, r+2), np.arange(c-1, c+2) # Moore neighborhood
    # neighs_r, neighs_c = np.meshgrid(range_r, range_c, indexing="ij")
    
    for rr, cc in zip(neighs_r, neighs_c):
         # Check various flags
         if (0 <= rr <= 10 and 0 <= cc <= 10 
         and mask[rr, cc] is True): # within lattice and mask is True
         valid_neighs.append(rr, cc)
```

I'm looking for a way that eliminates **both** for loops. Is there something like that?

Comment: The task is a bit unclear, can you perhaps provide an expected result for the ```test_arr = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))``` example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do n-D distance and nearest neighbor calculations on numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366421/how-to-do-n-d-distance-and-nearest-neighbor-calculations-on-numpy-arrays)

Comment: What is test_arr? where do you search for neighbours? Would give more details with some numerical examples

Comment: @playerJX1 Added an edit.